# Extract circles from one image after have apply the circular hough transform

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to extract the detected circles in one image using the circular hough transform. My idea is get every circle or separate each one to then get his color histogram features and after send this features to one classifier as SVM, ANN, KNN etc..
This is my input image:

[image]

I'm getting the circles of this way:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cv2.__version__
#read image
file = "lemon.png"
image = cv2.imread(file)
#BGR to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,
                           cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                           15, 
                           41,
                           param1=31,
                           param2=31,
                           minRadius=0,
                           maxRadius=33)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)


print("Number of circles: "+ str(len(circles[0,:])))


plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

The next step is try to extract those circles but I don't have idea how to do it.

[image]

Well guys I would like to see your suggestions, any I idea I will apreciate it.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Draw your circles as white filled on a black background the same size as your input. Then use this mask to blacken your input image everwhere where the mask is black.  `newimg = img.copy()` then `newimg[mask==0] = (0,0,0)`

Comment: Hi @fmw42 can you answer my question I will apreciate your idea. I don't know how draw inside a black background, I could create it  ´black = np.zeros(image.shape, image.dtype)´ but I don't kwno how I could fill this new black image inside the for loop of the circles `for i in circles[0,:]: ....`

Comment: Hi @fmw42 finally I could draw the circles inside the for loop `cv2.circle(new_image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),-1)` I just put -1 to fill every circle. Now at every iteration I should put that maks inside my input image. Great idea https://imgur.com/a/ZTq03sz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **binary mask** for every circle you detect. Use this mask to extract only the `ROIs` from the input image. Additionally, you can crop these `ROIs` and store them in a list to pass them to your classifier.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# image path
path = "C://opencvImages//"
file = path + "LLfN7.png"

image = cv2.imread(file)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,
                           cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                           15,
                           41,
                           param1=31,
                           param2=31,
                           minRadius=0,
                           maxRadius=33)

# Here are your circles:
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

# Get input size:
dimensions = image.shape

# height, width
height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]

# Prepare a list to store each ROI:
lemonROIs = []
```

The idea is that you process one circle at a step. Get the current circle, create a mask, mask the original input, crop the `ROI` and store it inside the list:

```
for i in circles[0, :]:

    # Prepare a black canvas:
    canvas = np.zeros((height, width))

    # Draw the outer circle:
    color = (255, 255, 255)
    thickness = -1
    centerX = i[0]
    centerY = i[1]
    radius = i[2]
    cv2.circle(canvas, (centerX, centerY), radius, color, thickness)

    # Create a copy of the input and mask input:
    imageCopy = image.copy()
    imageCopy[canvas == 0] = (0, 0, 0)

    # Crop the roi:
    x = centerX - radius
    y = centerY - radius
    h = 2 * radius
    w = 2 * radius

    croppedImg = imageCopy[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    # Store the ROI:
    lemonROIs.append(croppedImg)
```

For each circle you get a cropped ROI:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can pass that info to your classifier.

Comment: Hi @eldesgraciado thanks you man, this and excellent answer and fix my problem.I had drawn every circle in a black image inside the circles loop https://imgur.com/a/7F9bRSa because instead of get and big image for every circle. with your code we got a very tiny image for every circle, to send to the classifier I should ignore black pixels using a numpy mask ignoring zeros. Thanks also to fmw42 and you. Great idea! keep it up!